# Jenkins & Github, how to append a version number?

Tags: spring, maven, github, jenkins

We have 2 branches in github,

1. master
2. release

In our jenkins we have a job for each of these branches. 
We want to increment a version number programmatically for release each time jenkins builds the release. We want also to increment the version number in the github release branch. Can you give me some directions on how to do it and what jenkin plugins i need? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be performed using a simple command:

```
mvn release:prepare release:perform --batch-mode
```

Explanation:

```
release:prepare
```

Prepare for a release in SCM. Steps through several phases to ensure the POM is ready to be released and then prepares SCM to eventually contain a tagged version of the release and a record in the local copy of the parameters used. It will update your version number from e.g. "1.0.1-SNAPSHOT" to "1.0.1" and commit it to the tag. Also working version will be incremented and updated to "-SNAPSHOT" again, e.g. "1.0.2-SNAPSHOT".
This can be followed by a call to `release:perform`. For more info see [example](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-release-plugin/examples/prepare-release.html)

```
release:perform
```

Perform a release from SCM, either from a specified tag, or the tag representing the previous release in the working copy created by `release:prepare`. For more info see [example](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-release-plugin/examples/perform-release.html)

`--batch-mode` allows a non-interactive script executeion. For details please read about [maven-release-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/)

Answer (score 0):

Use the maven release plugin to handle incrementing the version number.  At that point all you have to do is have the Jenkins build run maven with the release plugin goals.

Here is a good article on it.
http://www.vineetmanohar.com/2009/10/how-to-automate-project-versioning-and-release-with-maven/

With that all you have to do in Jenkins is have it run the following command on the checked out repository.

```
mvn release:prepare release:perform -B
```